# How to match with a regex if a number in an array is in a range?

Tags: regex

I need to check with a regex expression if the second part of the entry is in a range. The entry would be for example: "25-2000". So the first number and the hyphen are not important.

I have taken the second part of the entry with expression:

```
[^-]*$
```

And I want to evaluate if the number is in range 1700-2100 with the expression:

```
(^(1[7-9][0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9]|2100)$)
```

I have tried to join both expression with brackets, but It doesn't work:

```
([^-]*$)(^(1[7-9][0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9]|2100)$)
```

Comment: Validating a wide number range with regex is a real headache.  If you're using a programming language like Java, C#, Node, Ruby, etc., then you should opt for using an inequality expression.

Comment: Use a negative lookahead if supported `(?![^-]*-)` or a lookbehind `(?<=-)` i.e. `(?<=-)((?:1[7-9]|20)\d\d|2100)$`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. As @TimBiegeleisen suggested, you may match the pattern and extract the second number from it, but to assert if it fits a range, you're better of going to the language constructs for the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `-` before the pattern that matches the number:

```
-((?:1[7-9]|20)\d\d|2100)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
-(?:1[789]\d\d|20\d\d|2100)$
```

If it matches anything, the number is within the range of 1700-2100.

You don't actually need to combine the two patterns, and you shouldn't combine patterns blindly by just adding brackets.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zFpZnG/1)